# Django - UPDATE user fields in two different views (forms)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-users

I have hard time with such a easy thing (I guess).

My aim is to create **two subpages with 2 different forms yet connected with the same user model**:

**/account/register.html** - page only to manage registration (create user with login,email,password)
**/account/questionnaire.html** - page for UPDATING the same user information such as age,weight,height etc.

I've got 'POST' communicates in server log but nothing appears when I'm checking up django admin site.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from account.models import UserProfile

class RegisterUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','password')

class RegisterUserInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('age','weight','height')
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from account.forms import RegisterUserForm, RegisterUserInfoForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def register(request):
        registered = False

        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = RegisterUserForm(data=request.POST)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()

                registered = True

            else:
                print(user_form.errors)

        else:
            user_form = RegisterUserForm()

        return render(request,'account/register.html',{
            'user_form':user_form,
            'registered':registered,
        })

@login_required
def questionnaire(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = RegisterUserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
        else:
            print(profile_form.errors)
    else:
        profile_form = RegisterUserInfoForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request,'account/questionnaire.html',{
        'profile_form':profile_form,
    })
```

**register.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>   
        <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" name="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**questionnaire.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_block %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>questionnaire</h1>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Save">
  </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view doesn't receive a POST request because you didn't provide an action attribute to your form tag. So, your form passes your POST request nowhere. Try it like this:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
  </form>
```

Also, you should definitely check django's built-in generic views: [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) and [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). They serve exactly for such purposes and makes almost everything for you.

Comment: thanks for answer but you also didn't provide action: `<form action="" method="post"> `, my register.html is working, but questionnaire.html not

Comment: I just showed you a missing thing by the example of questionnaire.html. You should, obviously, add the same `action=""` code to your second template as well.

Comment: i'm afraid it did't help

Comment: What is your output in this case?

Comment: I have age, weight, height fields shown in my questionnaire.html page so I fill them out. Then when I click button server is showing 'POST' in logs but nothing happens. In django admin panel I don't see any of those fields filled out.

Comment: Your RegisterUserInfoForm is tied to UserProfile model, not User model. So, in your view, you are passing User model instance to it. `RegisterUserInfoForm(instance=request.user)`. That should be the cause of your problem here.

Comment: You mean: `profile_form = RegisterUserInfoForm(instance=request.user)` ? Got it all the time

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly that. In your definition of RegisterUserInfoForm, you have UserProfile model in meta class. So you should try it like this: `profile_form = RegisterUserInfoForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)`

Comment: @kubeq24, I know I am very late. However, I have the exact same issue that you had faced. Please let me if the suggested solution worked for you? if not then what steps did you take to get around it? I have scratched every part of my head without any positive outcome